# How to require a library in Rails console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to run, line by line, a script written in Rails' console. It requires three libraries, 'net/http', 'uri' and 'json'.

When I enter

```
require 'library_name'
```

it returns "false", which I suppose means it did not run the library.

Am I right? How can I do this?

Comment: It's likely already loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I log what is happening in my server (localhost) ? Because if the library is already loaded that means I have a problem at my script. It should send curl requests to an API but it is not, apparently.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can [require](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) libraries in the console. The return value says if that library was already loaded in or not, because they are not loaded more than once. So, if you see `true` it means the library has been loaded, if you see `false` it means that the library was already loaded.